# The Maven error while trying to run on Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-8, windows-10

I have recently changed to Windows 10 machine, on which I am trying to run my maven project.
When I run `mvn clean install`, I am getting following error:

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven 2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project path:DataMapper:0.0.1 (C:\Users\Username\Downloads\DataMapper\DataMapper\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: **Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: proxy.example.com from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='proxy.example.com', userName='null', port=8088, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}** and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 10, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

My `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>az.dps.adrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataMapper</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.boris.winrun4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>WinRun4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If you will try to open the `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom` link, you will get a message `501 HTTPS Required. Use https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`. So, you need to change a path to Maven repository with using `https`.

Comment: Please change to HTTPS and then build with `mvn clean install -U`.

Answer (score 0):

We might need your maven settings xml. But anyway if I'm right based on your trace, you are still using http://repo.maven.apache.org or Maven Central changed its policy months ago and only allow **https**. Please try changing your mirrors to https://repo.maven.apache.org.

Comment: I have changed it now to https and still I get the same error.

Comment: This is the Settings.xml                                                                                 
  <settings>
<proxies>
 <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>